# How to achieve hierarchial filter in facets in typesense

Tags: vue-instant-search, typesense

I am using vue instantsearch component in the frontend UI with typesense. I have a particular use case to achieve. Please guide me how that could be achieved.
I have a product data and hierarchical category. I have already achieved normal search by facets such as category , brand, price and rating. However my requirment is as:

```
Clothes
      ->Mens Clothing
         -> Tshirt
         -> Pant
      -> Womens Clothing
         -> Tops
         -> Ladies pant
```

Taking the example of above hierarchal category. I would like filter the product by category. eg. (Mens Clothing) then I would only like to see Tshirt and Pant in the category facets ie the children categories of Mens Clothing only.
Let me know How can I achieve such.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`ais-hierarchical-menu` widget](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/hierarchical-menu/vue/).

Make sure that you structure the data in Typesense as described in [this section](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/hierarchical-menu/vue/#requirements) for the widget to work.

The browse by categories widget on [this page](https://ecommerce-store.typesense.org) is an example implementation of this widget.